Annotate images in figure with text labels
I am writing a document in latex and I have a figure that contains three images. I want an easy way to be able to label these (a), (b), and (c) respectively. I had a solution which utilized the subfigure package but this doesn't work with the documentclass I need to use (for a scientific journal). I am thinking that perhaps the easiest thing to do would be to annotate the images and just add text over top the image with the label. How can I do this though? The code that I am using for the figure is:
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{1D_Grav.png}
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{1D_Saw.png}
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{1D_EnergyPlot.png}      
\caption{(a) Snapshots of the solution, $\phi$, with gravity acting are shown at $t=0,5,150,300$ (blue, green, red, cyan). (b) Snapshots of the solution, $\phi$, with a SAW potential applied are shown at $t=0,0.5,2,11$ (blue, green, red, cyan). (c) The normalized free energy, $E[\phi]/E[\phi_0]$, calculated at each time step for both simulations. In (a) and (b), the final times shown correspond to the steady state solutions.}
\label{fig:1D_grav}
\end{figure} 


You should make a small, but compilable test file, including your unproblematic class. This will make sure that the solutions you'll get will actually work with your class.

Usually you can use either package subcaption or subfig, but only if the used class is supported by the package and no other package for sub-figures is already used. So more information would be needed to give an answer, i.e., if you already failed and think, this is because of the class, which is currently a blackbox for us.
